# SSIS Calculation with different total

Tags: sql, ssis, olap, cube, measures

I'm trying to show the amount of days a company travel has taken. The sales employee doesn't enter the exact amount so it is calculated in SQL and in the data load to `DWH` it is added to the `TravelID`. If `travelID` exists 3 times due to 3 trip lines connected to it, each line gets the amount of 3.

DWH Database

```
TravelID   1234       TriplineID   2345     #Days  3
TravelID   1234       TriplineID   2346     #Days  3
TravelID   1234       TriplineID   2347     #Days  3
```

So one `TravelID` can have multiple `TriplineID`'s

The problem is when i want to make my cube measure, is that it counts up all the 3's. 
In this case it shows me #Days is 9 for one travel, while it must be 3:

```
                                     #Days
--TravelID      1234
     --TripLineID   -2345            3
     --TripLineID   -2346            3
     --TripLineID   -2347            3
     Total                           9
```

I then thought i'd devide it by a Count of the rows.
`([Measures].[# Days] / [Measures].[Count])`

Then it shows me a partly correct result:

```
                                     #Days
--TravelID      1234
     --TripLineID   -2345            3
     --TripLineID   -2346            3
     --TripLineID   -2347            3
     Total                           3
Total                                2
```

Since there obviously are multiple `TravelID`'s, it also devides that Total, while there it must actually make the sum of the previous Totals.

What would be an efficient way to implement this? I spend a whole day cracking my head over this but i can't seem to find a good solution.

Here is a bigger picture of the problem:

```
                                     #Days
--TravelID      1234
     --TripLineID   -2345            3
     --TripLineID   -2346            3
     --TripLineID   -2347            3
     Total                           3
--TravelID      1235
     --TripLineID   -2348            4
     --TripLineID   -2349            4
     --TripLineID   -2350            4
     Total                           4
Total                                2
```

Where the 2 here should have been 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i have found up to now, is to create a second fact table. I was trying to avoid this but i didn't see any other way.